# Huge GC perforamance problems with big allocated data blocks

Tags: go, garbage-collection

I have just noticed that if I allocate a huge memory block in programm. GC will eat all programm time.

Here is POC.

https://gist.github.com/martende/252f403f0c17cb489de4

```
func main() {
    //////////////// !!!!!!!
    /* If I uncomment 2 lines below programm runs fast */
    nodesPool := make([]int, 300e6, 300e6)
    _ = nodesPool
    //////////////////////7

    file, _ := os.Open("result.txt")
    defer file.Close()

    reader := bufio.NewReader(file)

    var lastLinkIdx = 1 // Dont use first element use 0 as saver

    cnt:=  0
    totalB := 0

    for {
       l, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
       if err == io.EOF {
    fmt.Println("EOF")
        break
    }

    cnt+=1      
    totalB+=len(l)

    lines := strings.Split(l, ":")
    nodeId,_ := strconv.Atoi(lines[0])
    _ = nodeId

    linkIdsStr  := strings.Split(lines[1], ",")
    var ii = len(linkIdsStr)
    _ = ii
    /*      ... */
}

fmt.Println("pool ",cnt,totalB,lastLinkIdx)


}
```

I think that GC tries somehow move the huge memory block , is it actually possible to allocate memory out of GC but leave GC for all other libraries becuase even ReadLine need it.

Here is profiling with memory block.

```
Total: 1445 samples
     428  29.6%  29.6%      722  50.0% runtime.sweepone
     375  26.0%  55.6%      375  26.0% markroot
     263  18.2%  73.8%      263  18.2% runtime.xadd
     116   8.0%  81.8%      116   8.0% strings.Count
      98   6.8%  88.6%      673  46.6% strings.genSplit
      34   2.4%  90.9%       44   3.0% runtime.MSpan_Sweep
      25   1.7%  92.7%      729  50.4% MCentral_Grow
      17   1.2%  93.8%       19   1.3% syscall.Syscall
       9   0.6%  94.5%        9   0.6% runtime.memclr
       9   0.6%  95.1%        9   0.6% runtime.memmove
```

Here is profiling without memory block.

```
  98  27.0%  27.0%       98  27.0% strings.Count
  93  25.6%  52.6%      228  62.8% strings.genSplit
  45  12.4%  65.0%       45  12.4% scanblock
  24   6.6%  71.6%       28   7.7% runtime.MSpan_Sweep
  13   3.6%  75.2%       74  20.4% runtime.mallocgc
  12   3.3%  78.5%       12   3.3% runtime.memclr
   8   2.2%  80.7%        8   2.2% MHeap_ReclaimList
   8   2.2%  82.9%       11   3.0% syscall.Syscall
   6   1.7%  84.6%       44  12.1% MHeap_Reclaim
   6   1.7%  86.2%        6   1.7% markonly
```

Comment: You realise you are setting up an array of 300 million ints.

Comment: 1. Which version of Go? 2. Your nodesPool is (too) big. 3. GC doesn't move. 4. There is no clever/easy/safe way to allocate un-GCed memory.

Comment: go version go1.3 linux/amd64
I understand that nodesPool is big but i really need it

Comment: You need 300 million integers in memory all at one time ... ? Is there no other option available to you? Perhaps loading segments in at a time.. ?

Comment: Yes It 1GB of memory -for this block. For 32GB machine it not so much. I want to load my whole database to make in-memory computation.

Comment: Now I am trying to rewrite this code on c++ , but it would be too painfool if it be a showstopper for golang

Comment: ..you do seem to be creating a lot of garbage for the GC to collect. Not only are you loading in 1GB worth of integers.. but you're also creating multiple strings per line of that file which are only valid within that main loop. You might consider trying to lower the garbage you're generating by moving some of the string allocations outside of that tight loop and reusing variables. See if that helps the GC cope.

Comment: In the POC, I am only creating the huge BLOCK and even not use it , if i remove it , GC make its work pretty well - even with alot of tiny strings. This means that only composition of two actions makes problem: huge block + normal computation with tiny strings. Ofcourse I can rewrite Datastream processing to lower GC usage but it is only POC in real life in the other part of code I anyway want to use GC benefits

Comment: Right, I misunderstood.

Comment: What is the behaviour on tip? I think 1.4 incorporates some GC stuff, so it would be worth a try.

Comment: @OlegGolovanov: You need to provide us with a small sample of results.txt data.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/martende/cdd45b241a4798b54a70 but real problems starts with datacount > 400k . Here is diskussion on golang forum https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/-Dq4WkivD2E

Comment: I would try with Go 1.3.3 (latest stable version). They made some improvements to the precise garbage collector. Maybe the GC is considering every value in the array as a potential pointer (conservative GC, prior to Go 1.3)

Comment: You could look at reducing garbage by using, say, `bufio.Reader`'s `ReadSlice` method, which gives you a slice pointing into its temporary buffer. Depending on the computation, maybe there's some way to do it in chunks.

Comment: Out of curiosity - what happens when you don't use `make`, but instead declare a large array normally? Maybe it is `make` that is being pre-empted by the GC as it allocates memory.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: It does not changes behaviour. go 1.3.3 1.4 also . I can't believe that I am first who has tried to work with a huge array in go. Obviously I am doing something wrong.

Comment: I replaced my answer about tuning for allocations during parsing with Dmitry's report of the performance bug from the golang-nuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dmitry Vyukov of the Go team [says](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-nuts/-Dq4WkivD2E/neDouOIs8MAJ) this is a [Go runtime performance issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/9265) you can trigger with a huge allocation, and that as a workaround, "you can collect the large object as soon as it become[s] dead and increase GOGC right after that."

Broadly, the GitHub issue says that the runtime creates a lot of memory-management structures (spans) that it then keeps around indefinitely and has to sweep on every GC. Going by the issue tags, a fix is targeted for Go 1.5.

[His sample with workaround](http://play.golang.org/p/PaxuZpREa4) is:

```
package main

import (
    "runtime"
    "runtime/debug"
)

var x = make([]byte, 1<<20)
var y []byte
var z []byte

func main() {
    y = make([]byte, 1<<30)
    y = nil
    runtime.GC()
    debug.SetGCPercent(1000)
    for i := 0; i < 1e6; i++ {
        z = make([]byte, 8192)
    }
}
```

(Some comments are about a totally different answer and code sample focused on avoiding allocations that I've edited out. There's no way to "tell" StackOverflow this is a new answer, so they remain.)

Comment: BUG REPORT: `panic: bufio: buffer full`

Comment: thanks. but try please not 5000 but minimum 500000 and even better 100M for me here problems with GC become more o less noticable.

Comment: OK, took out my allocation-pinching code and put in what Dmitry Vyukov said on golang-nuts. (Is there a better way to replace an answer?)